# What's the term for siblings born 1+ years apart on the same day?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

What is the term for two siblings born on the same calendar day, one or more years apart? I know there's a term, and I'd know it if I saw it, but I can't for the life of me remember it.

Comment: "Cheated out of a birthday party", perhaps?

Comment: Man, you're tellin' me. My sister and I share a birthday, two years apart, meaning we shared presents and birthday parties all my life.

Comment: *I know there's a term* —how do you know that?

Comment: On the plus side, even though I had to share cakes and parties, my brother is 9 years older, and a baby sister who never broke or got lost is a terrible birthday present for a 9 year old boy.

Comment: Before answering this question, please see [this meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/requests-for-coinage)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aside from saying that you "share a birthday", I am not sure that such a term exists. If it does it isn't likely to be very well known. Restricting it to only match *siblings* is likely to make things less likely to match up perfectly.

Generally, special birthdays are given a modifier. Most of these are just off the cuff:

- holiday birthday
- shared birthday
- golden birthday
- half-birthday

Other words that could work apart from "shared":

- joint birthday
- combined birthday

You could also go the other way with it and accentuate the negative:

- split birthday

Comment: I guess the Internet has spoken, whatever word I heard of for this was made up. Thanks!

Comment: Discussion on meta notwithstanding, all words were at one time "made up". If this is not the place to do so, that doesn't mean you shouldn't feel free elsewhere.

Comment: *"Aside from saying that you "share a birthday", I am not sure that such a term exists."* __ I am happy to award you the bounty @MrHen for your now-proved-very-correct intuition that no such word exists! [If such a word/ phrase existed I am satisfied that somebody would have posted it as an answer this week, particularly with the extra attention drawn to this question by posting a bounty.]

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of "Irish twins"?  It's not exactly what you were asking about, but it is the only relevant term I can think of that you might be referring to.

Irish twins are siblings who are close enough in age to be mistaken for twins.  I would guess that the expression stems from a perception that Catholics have children in close succession.

https://www.verywell.com/irish-twins-meaning-2447174

Comment: Thanks for introducing an intriguing term I had never heard before, @PJB -- here in India I had 3 schoolmates around my own age, brothers who were born in 3 consecutive years -- I suppose that makes them *Irish triplets* according to the article you linked!

Answer (score 1):

I might call them "yearlings", being a little cheeky.

Although the common usage is a foal between one and two years old, apparently there is a legit usage relating to a one year span:

> Yearling (*adjective*): of a year's duration or standing
> <sub>SOURCE: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yearling?s=t)</sub>

Comment: When there is no obvious term and these formidable scholars at ELU have not located any obscure term, a good measure of cheekiness is permitted; thanks @DukeZhou! Would you agree that English.SE and Literature.SE are topically mutually exclusive, as it seems to me?

Comment: @EnglishStudent I'd say English.SE is the place for grammar, usage, and etymology, whereas Literature.SE is the place for analysis of literary work, but possibly not entirely exclusive.

Comment: *"possibly not entirely exclusive"* __ thank you: I was interested if there is *any*  areas of overlap between these 2 sites in your experience, @Duke Zhou because I could find very very few references to literature here at ELU.

Answer (score 0):

Having a sibling born 2 years to the day from me, I have searched for this term most of my life, but not found one. As such, and as language is merely an expression of randomly used phrases that come into popular acceptance, I decided to make up my own. As a play on the term "Irish Twin" for a sibling born in the same year, I refer to mine as my "Double Dutch twin".